# Java8 FileSystems.getDefault throw UnsupportedCharsetException

Tags: java, character-encoding, java-8, filesystems

I have a very simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    FileSystems.getDefault();
}
```

It runs good in Java7

But throws UnsupportedCharsetException: GBK in java8, full stack as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.<init>(WindowsFileSystem.java:67)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.<init>(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:53)
    at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.create(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:36)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.getDefaultProvider(FileSystems.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.access$000(FileSystems.java:89)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:98)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:96)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.defaultFileSystem(FileSystems.java:96)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(FileSystems.java:90)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault(FileSystems.java:176)
    at com.yy.ent.test.Test1.main(Test1.java:26)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: GBK
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:531)
    at sun.nio.fs.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:41)
    ... 12 more
```

I am using windows7 in Chinese
And my java8 is:

- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It would seem that the JRE installer only installs "extended" character sets if the locale requires it: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html Try installing the JDK or set your user's region and langauge to Chinese (Simplified) and re-install the JRE.

Comment: re-install save my life, thank u very much! @AlastairMcCormack

Comment: Excellent. I've created an answer for other people's benefit. You may want to consider the accepted answer to help other people too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that the JRE installer only installs "extended" character sets if the locale requires it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

> Oracle's Java SE Development Kit 7 (Java SE 7) for all platforms (Solaris, Linux, and Microsoft Windows) and the Java SE Runtime Environment 7 (JRE 7) for Solaris and Linux support all encodings shown on this page. Oracle's JRE 7 for Microsoft Windows may be installed as a complete international version or as a European languages version. **By default, the JRE 7 installer installs a European languages version if it recognizes that the host operating system only supports European languages.** If the installer recognizes that any other language is needed, or if the user requests support for non-European languages in a customized installation, a complete international version is installed. The European languages version only supports the encodings shown in the following Basic Encoding Set table. The international version (which includes the lib/charsets.jar file) supports all encodings shown on this page.

This should also apply to Java 8. I read this to mean, that the JDK supports all charsets (includes `lib/charsets.jar`). The JRE tries to install a minimal environment and won't install extended characters sets, such as GBK, if the installer is being run by a user with a European locale.

**Solution:** 
Try installing the JDK or set your user's region and language to Chinese (Simplified), then re-install the JRE.

Comment: My first installation of java8 was jdk1.8.0_45, and then updated to jdk1.8.0_66 by Oracle Auto-update tools, which caused this exception.
Re-install can solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Either try changing "sun.jnu.encoding" property to something else, for example:

```
-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
```

or check if your JVM contains "lib/charsets.jar" which is required for GBK support according to (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Comment: From looking at [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/nio/fs/Util.java#41), it seems that changing this property to a common charset will solve the issue, especially as the `WindowsFileSystem` does not use that value at all. Apparently, it’s only used by the Unix/Linux file system implementation.

Comment: There is something wrong with my java8 installation. I can't find charsets.jar which cause this exception. Re-install save my life. Thank u very much!